# Why can't I find the vscode live share extension on linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On the open source vscode for arch linux(code-oss) I can't find the live share extension but on my pc with windows the live share extension is the first search result in the extensions panel.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the open source version of vscode doesn't have live share but visual-studio-code-bin from the AUR does have it.

Comment: For me fresh installation didn't have live share automatically. I needed to install live share extension from Microsoft. Then after authenticating I could use the live share without any issue on LInux and live share button also appeared at the bottom bar. Running Manjaro myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AUR [code-marketplace](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/code-marketplace) to add Microsoft's VSCode marketplace; then you should be able to find and install Live Share.
This way, you can **theoretically** use Live Code without using the proprietary [visual-studio-code-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/visual-studio-code-bin). Note that this probably violates Microsoft's terms of use, though.

Quoting the maintainer:

> This package basically installs a hook that will patch /usr/lib/code/product.json to use vscode marketplace every time community/code is updated.

Unfortunately, though installable, LiveShare **does not work with *code-oss*** as of writing, because some kind of internal API isn't available.